# How to handle views inside views when using the back button in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I have an App which lists all my ToDos by category.

To do this my, inital thought was to write two For Each Loops. The first one to iterate over the groups and the second to itereate over the todo items per category.
But XCode said, that this was too complex to handle in one single view.

So I split up the views.
HomeView.
ForEach category display RowView (parameter: category).
ForEach todo display DetailView (parameter: category, todo).
-> The DetailView holds the NavigationLinks for the respective todo.

Now when I click on a todo and try to navigate back with the built in back button, does this cause problems with the user interaction?

Because after going back, I can't click on any todos anymore.

Comment: have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you need help debugging something it would be best to add the code that is relevant to your question.

Comment: It seems you try to add all navigation in only one view or put different level of navigation in the same view. In your case a navigation link should have for destination a new view, like CategoryView, ToDoView DetailsView